# ¿Como modificar un TextView con el contenido de un SMS en Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo el siguiente código para recibir `SMS` en la clase `ReceptorSMS`. Necesito que el contenido de la variable `Mensaje` se vea en la pantalla principal de mi App, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo. ACTUALIZO: Me sugirieron crear un método publico en mi MainActivity:

```
    public void actualizaMensaje(String msj){
    txtEstadoDeLaAlarma=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Estado);
    txtEstadoDeLaAlarma.setText(msj);
    }
```

Y llamarlo luego en el BroadcastReceiver

```
public class ReceptorSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String Mensaje;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        MainActivity Principal = new MainActivity();

        Log.i("ReceptorSMS", "SMS recibido");

        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();

        if (b != null) {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) b.get("pdus");

            SmsMessage[] mensajes = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < mensajes.length; i++) {
                mensajes[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

                String idMensaje = mensajes[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                String textoMensaje = mensajes[i].getMessageBody();

                Log.i("ReceptorSMS", "Remitente: " + idMensaje);
                Log.i("ReceptorSMS", "Mensaje: " + textoMensaje);

                // Toast.makeText(context, "Recibido: " + idMensaje + " " + textoMensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // TODO Indicar el estado de la alarma (Activada/Desactivada Luces On / OFF) En el label txtEst
                if (textoMensaje.indexOf("Arming")!=-1) {
                    // Arming encontrada en el mensaje
                    Log.i("ReceptorSMS","LA ALARMA ESTA ACTIVADA");
                    Mensaje="Alarma Activada";
                }
                if (textoMensaje.indexOf("Disarming")!=-1) {
                    // Disarming encontrada en el mensaje
                    Log.i("ReceptorSMS","LA ALARMA ESTA DESACTIVADA");
                    Mensaje="Alarma Desactivada";
                }
                Toast.makeText(context, Mensaje, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Principal.actualizaMensaje(Mensaje); // Acá llamo método público
            }
        }
    }
}
```

He intentado con

```
    TextView txtEstadoDeLaAlarma;
    txtEstadoDeLaAlarma=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Estado);
```

Pero obtengo error en  `findViewById()`

Y llamando al método desde el BroadcastReceiver se cierra la aplicación; aquí dejo lo que dice el log:

07-20 11:40:01.255 11031-11031/com.mzadigital.carlos.coalarm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.mzadigital.carlos.coalarm, PID: 11031
                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.mzadigital.carlos.coalarm.ReceptorSMS: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:149)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:118)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:152)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:204)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:184)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:518)
                                                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:189)
                                                                                   at com.mzadigital.carlos.coalarm.MainActivity.actualizaMensaje(MainActivity.java:78)
                                                                                   at com.mzadigital.carlos.coalarm.ReceptorSMS.onReceive(ReceptorSMS.java:62)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2588)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:149) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1366) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700) 
                                                                                   at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102) 
07-20 11:40:01.365 11031-11031/com.mzadigital.carlos.coalarm I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 11031 SIG: 9

Comment: Agrega la clase que carga mediante setContentView(), el layout que contiene el TextView llamado Estado. @CarlosMammoli

Comment: No se si entendí bien pero lo cargo en mi MainActivity

Comment: entonces en tu MainActivity agrega el método que propongo en mi respuesta y mandalo llamar desde  tu broadcastreceiver.

Comment: En eso estoy. La verdad es que si bien con otros lenguajes no tengo problema hace muy poco que estoy con java / android studio. Como lo llamo desde el broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0):

Tu broadcast receiver no carga un layout que contenga el TextView indicado, por lo tanto no puedes uar el método `findViewById(R.id.Estado);` , como opción puedes llamar un método desde el broadcastreceiver un método que se encuentre dentro de la clase que carga el layout que contiene el `TextView` y realizar la actualización del texto.

```
TextView txtEstadoDeLaAlarma;

public void actualizaMensaje(String msj){
  txtEstadoDeLaAlarma=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Estado);
  txtEstadoDeLaAlarma.setText(msj);
}
```

Comment: me puedes ayduar a implementar un Pull to refresh en una lista porfavor

Comment: si claro! agrega la pregunta con tus datos.

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/88121/actualizar-una-lista-personalizada-con-swiperefreshlayout-en-android-pull-to-r

Answer (score 0):

Respondo mi propia pregunta. Espero pueda servirle a otro. Probando se me ocurrió crear una clase que llamo Estados:

```
import android.widget.TextView;

class Estados { // suprimo public (n)
private static TextView obj;

void actualizaMensaje(String msj){
    obj.setText(msj);
}

void Iniciar(TextView obj1){
    obj=obj1;
    obj.setText("Esperando Datos...");
}}
```

La clase tiene dos métodos;

**Iniciar**, al que paso como parámetro el TextView que quiero actualizar y lo dejo en una variable tipo static (esto no me gusta pero no se me ocurre otra manera)

**actualizaMensaje**, al que se pasa como parámetro el Mensaje que quiero ver en el TextView.

A la clase la llamo tanto desde mi MainActivity, invocando el método Iniciar como desde el BroadcastReceiver invocando el método actualizaMensaje. No es prolijo, pero por ahora funciona. Me gustaría mucho saber que opinan o ver alternativas.

Answer (score 0):

El BroadcastReceiver  funciona aun si cerraste la aplicacion si lo pusiste en el `AndroidManifest.xml` como se pone habitualmente. Si te mandan un sms y la aplicacion esta cerrada el codigo falla tambien ya que el TextView no esta creado.
Lo mejor es Guardar los sms en una base de datos o en las SharedPreferences
y crear un SharedPreferenceListener en la actividad del TextView.

En la linea  `Principal.actualizaMensaje(Mensaje);`

```
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
   editor.putString("text_sms", context);
   editor.commit();
```

Esto guarda el ultimo sms en las preferencias de la aplicacion.

Modificas en la actividad principal este metodo

```
public void actualizaMensaje(){
    txtEstadoDeLaAlarma=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Estado);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); 
String msj= prefs.getString("text_sms", "");
    txtEstadoDeLaAlarma.setText(msj);
    }
```

Lo pones en el onResume  para que si  el sms te llego al estar cerrada la app
Y creas un listener para los cambios en las preferencias:

```
 //Campo privado
    SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener ;
....
    //en el metodo oncreate
    listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
            actualizaMensaje();
      }
    };

@Override     
protected void onResume() {  
        super.onResume(); 
        actualizaMensaje();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);
}
```

...

```
//en el metodo  onpause
@Override     
protected void onPause() {         
    super.onPause();          
     PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(listener);

}
```